# snowflake odbc driver externalbrowser sso authentication

Tags: sql, odbc, single-sign-on, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've setup a system DSN to connect to a snowflake server.

When I do something as basic as using the SQL Import/Export wizard to transfer the contents of a single table from snowflake to an on-prem SQL server, why does snowflake execute the challenge request 6 times!?

Comment: By challenge do you mean opening the browser 6 times? And do you have an [ODBC log](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-generate-log-file-on-Snowflake-connectors#ODBC) to see what is happening?

Comment: correct, the browser opens and redirects to our login provider multiple times, which triggers the 2 factor challenge as well.  if i run the resulting package created by the import/export wizard.  the login is still currently required 3 times.

Comment: That means your application is opening multiple connections, so connection caching is probably something that will help minimizing the prompts.

Comment: I actually edited the save dtsx file and disabled all pre-validation, and enabled connection sharing, within ssis/ssdt, prior to executing.  I've got logs generated, but not sure what I should look for, or who I should securely share them with to see if there's an issue in the odbc driver.  there's no control over the wizard, where you're prompted 6 times.  run stand-alone from the save file, the job still prompts 3 times, even with the connection changes I made to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [connection caching](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-use.html#using-connection-caching-to-minimize-the-number-of-prompts-for-authentication-optional) feature?  I've heard good things if your team would be willing to test, perhaps first with a non-prod account.

Comment: I've tried contacting our snowflake dba, but haven't gotten a response.

Comment: @DanW I hope you do. I'm optimistic this feature would solve your troubles.